# Source attachment does not contain the source

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse and I am implementing some methods, but during implementation I see the following error

[image]

The attached Source is already on the file jdk1.8.0_281/src.zip, as shown.

[image]

And the same problem appears with respect to DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.

Where is the problem?

Thanks for help

Comment: If I remember correctly the source of the 'sun.reflect' code was not included in the JDK in Java 8. These classes are moved to 'jdk.reflect' in Java 9 and the source is included.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I solve the problem without changing the Java version

Comment: You would have to find the source somewhere else and add it to the src.zip. Why do you want to see the source anyway? This is very low level stuff.

Comment: I am trying to add the source so that the implementation process can take place without problems. I am a beginner and do not know if I am thinking correctly

Comment: If your Installed JREs preference page is using `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\jre` or anything under it, try using `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281` instead.

Comment: You don't need the source of those classes or any other classes in the JDK, they are just provided to help you understand what the code does.